# Building whole SSAS cube does not work, building dimension by dimension works - build order?

Tags: ssas, bids, dimension

I am having a strange problem when building a cube on SSAS. I have a fact table, let's say FactActivity. Then I have a dimension DimActivity, which has a 1 to 1 relationship with this fact, and all the foreign keys are bound to the dimension. So date dimensions, product dimensions and so on, are all bound to the DimActivity.

When I build the whole cube, it seems it is building the fact before the dimension, therefore it gives me errors. If I however, manually build the dimension before the fact, it works.

Is there anywhere in the SSAS that I can configure the build order, other than doing this from SSIS with the use of the Analysis Services Processing Task?

Many thanks!

Comment: Above you said "When I build the whole cube".  I think you need to be more precise as this could have many meanings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who are encountering similar problems....

The reason I was getting occasionally cube processing errors, is that the refreshing was happening at the same time - due to scheduled hourly imports.

I am now using logs to see what SSIS package is running. When importing activity, I inserted a record into this table, with a "Running" status.

Before processing the cube, I have a semaphore to check if records in this table, which are data imports and have a "Running" status. I only allow the refresh of the cube to happen if no imports are currently running. When the cube is processing, the imports also have a semaphore, and will not start importing, unless no cube processing is currently "Running".

After implementing this logic, I've never gotten any errors when processing the cubes.

Answer (score 1):

Processing a cube will not process the dimensions it relates to because they are constructed as separate entities in SSAS. In practice, this means that a dimension can exist, be processed and accessed without a relationship to a cube.

There is no such thing as a "general build order to configure". It is up to you to decide how AS objects should be processed. There are many tools that facilitate this, and they will all do the same thing: construct XMLA scripts to run on the AS server.

1. SSIS: Analysis Services Processing task
2. Configure a SQL agent job.
3. Perform a manual process using SSMS.
4. Program your processing activities using AMO
5. ...

Important is that you should process your dimensions before you process your cube. A simple solution is to process the entire SSAS database (containing your cubes and dimensions). This way, SSAS will automatically process the dimensions before processing the cubes.

[Documentation on processing Analysis Services objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174860%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I am getting around it by using the SSIS processing task, but thought something from BIDS should be able to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

When Processing a Dimension or the whole cube, before you click 'Run', click the 'Change Settings...' button. There you can change the way it should process. This link describes the effect of the options available.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174774.aspx

HTH